# How to resize VirtualBox disk on Mac?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My VB disk size is 50GB. I'm running Win7 on it. The host is a Mac. I'd like to increase the size to 75GB.  I run this command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 75000 "/Users/me/VirtualBox VMs/Win7vb/Win7vb.vdi"
```

The output is:

> 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

When I check the VB settings for this VM, it shows:

> Virtual Size: 73.24GB
>   Actual Size: 48.74GB

In the Win7 VM, I see a capacity of 53GB. This is a problem because the Win7 VM only has 5MB of free space.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: You have to use Windows now to expand the storage space.

Answer (score 3):

If I am right, you resized the drive correctly, but you didn't resize the drive in Windows VM. Search in VM for *Create and format hard disk and partitions*.

[image: screen1]

In this utility check if there is no free space (unformated space or unallocated space) on your disk. If yes, then extend it.

[image]